# Composer Update

Tags: symfony2, symfony, composer

Hola tengo un problema cuando ejecuto el comando `sudo composer update` 
me genera el siguiente error

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                                                                      
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" 
file could not be downloaded:   failed to open stream: 
Unable to find the    socket transport "10.1.80.219" - did you forget to enable   
it when you configured PHP?
```

Si lo ejecuto con `composer update` me genera otro error:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                           
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded:    
SSL    operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:  
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol                                                                
Failed to enable crypto                                                                                                            
failed to open stream: operation failed
```

Cuando ejecuto `composer install`

```
 Problem 1
- besimple/soap-client v0.2.6 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- besimple/soap-client v0.2.6 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
- Installation request for besimple/soap-client v0.2.6 -> satisfiable by besimple/soap-client[v0.2.6].
```

Si me pueden orientar como puedo solucionar el problema, muchas gracias!

Comment: has verificado el acceso a internet? parece un problema de red

Comment: Acceso a internet tengo, probe con *composer install* y me genera un error de soap

Comment: prueba `composer self-update`

Comment: me da el siguiente error *Command "self-update" is not defined.* voy a probar desinstalar composer con apt y luego instalarlo de nuevo con la documentaciòn oficial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude resolverlo de la siguiente forma, me conecte con mi servidor de desarrollo por

```
ssh <nombreservidor>
```

Con la contraseña y usuario, si es necesario, depende de como este configurado. El cli es paso a paso y va pidiendo los datos.

Una vez, ejecuta `sudo composer install` y `composer upate`, no necesite ejecutar sudo en el segundo comando.

Finalmente, ejecute un clear cache y funciono bien. Mi error fue intentar ejecutarlo localmente y no desde el servidor.